# Find Frequency of Phishing Attacks on Websites

Tags: phishing

I am trying to do some comparison based on frequency of phishing attacks on different sites.

[Phishtank](https://www.phishtank.com/target_search.php) lists phishing attack against target websites, but looking at the unknown target data available on phishtank it seems that targets were identified for only a fraction of the attacks. Also, since data is based on user reports only, it can not be a reliable source for attack frequency.

Now I have two questions.

1. Is there any other source which keeps a track of phishing attacks on different sites?
2. What would be the easiest way to identify unknown targets from phishtank? I can do that manually since with most of the valid reports there is a screenshot attached which usually has the logo/name of target sites. What would be the best OCR tool to use for this?

Comment: Do you care about capturing data for your own website or general statistics about popular websites?

Comment: Certainly you can see the difficultly of gathering the data you want. It can only be based on user reports and nothing stops anyone from putting up a fake login page with some company's logo on it. In fact, one site (URL) could be configured to show a range of different company's logins. And these are not attacks *on* the other sites. These are attacks on the users of those sites.